# Why Eclipse keeps crashing when i try to calculate this loop?

Tags: java

the program is about to calculate the average of numbers. Sorry ==if  no number is inputted

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int summa=0;
  int antal=0;
  String indata= showInputDialog("Ange ett tal");
    while(indata!=null) {    
         int tal=Integer.parseInt(indata);
         antal= antal+1;
         summa=summa+tal;
    }
    if(antal>0) {          
        double medelv=(double)summa/(double)antal;
        showInputDialog("Medelvärde av de 5 talen"+ medelv);                    
    }
    else {
        showMessageDialog(null,"du måste ange ett tal" );
    }       
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using a [desk check](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=deskcheck&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) approach to test your code and verify it's logic

Comment: Rubber duck debugging is another term for the above. But a small nitpick -- *Eclipse* isn't "crashing", but rather *your program* is crashing. Eclipse happens to be doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your while loop is causing the crash because the variable indata is never changed inside of it, meaning that the loop will run indefinitely with no alternate path to exit it.

```
while(indata!=null) {
     int tal=Integer.parseInt(indata);
     antal= antal+1;
     summa=summa+tal;
}
```